# Cuda 11.0 installs 11.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, nvidia, dpkg, cuda

I am following [this guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal) which says:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin

sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.debsudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/7fa2af80.pub

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

I get a `cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_amd64.deb` file.

At the stage of executing the `sudo apt-get -y install cuda` command I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-11-1 cuda-command-line-tools-11-1 cuda-compiler-11-1 cuda-cudart-11-1
  cuda-cudart-dev-11-1 cuda-cuobjdump-11-1 cuda-cupti-11-1 cuda-cupti-dev-11-1
  cuda-demo-suite-11-1 cuda-documentation-11-1 cuda-driver-dev-11-1
  cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-455 cuda-gdb-11-1 cuda-libraries-11-1
  cuda-libraries-dev-11-1 cuda-memcheck-11-1 cuda-nsight-11-1
  cuda-nsight-compute-11-1 cuda-nsight-systems-11-1 cuda-nvcc-11-1
  cuda-nvdisasm-11-1 cuda-nvml-dev-11-1 cuda-nvprof-11-1 cuda-nvprune-11-1
  cuda-nvrtc-11-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-1 cuda-nvtx-11-1 cuda-nvvp-11-1
  cuda-runtime-11-1 cuda-samples-11-1 cuda-sanitizer-11-1 cuda-toolkit-11-1
  cuda-tools-11-1 cuda-visual-tools-11-1 dkms libcublas-11-1
  libcublas-dev-11-1 libcufft-11-1 libcufft-dev-11-1 libcurand-11-1
  libcurand-dev-11-1 libcusolver-11-1 libcusolver-dev-11-1 libcusparse-11-1
  libcusparse-dev-11-1 libnpp-11-1 libnpp-dev-11-1 libnvidia-cfg1-455
  libnvidia-common-455 libnvidia-compute-455 libnvidia-decode-455
  libnvidia-encode-455 libnvidia-extra-455 libnvidia-fbc1-455 libnvidia-gl-455
  libnvidia-ifr1-455 libnvjpeg-11-1 libnvjpeg-dev-11-1 libxnvctrl0
  nsight-compute-2020.2.0 nsight-systems-2020.3.4 nvidia-compute-utils-455
  nvidia-dkms-455 nvidia-driver-455 nvidia-kernel-common-455
  nvidia-kernel-source-455 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  nvidia-utils-455 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455
Suggested packages:
  menu
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-455:i386 libnvidia-decode-455:i386
  libnvidia-encode-455:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386
  libnvidia-gl-455:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-compute-450-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda cuda-11-1 cuda-command-line-tools-11-1 cuda-compiler-11-1
  cuda-cudart-11-1 cuda-cudart-dev-11-1 cuda-cuobjdump-11-1 cuda-cupti-11-1
  cuda-cupti-dev-11-1 cuda-demo-suite-11-1 cuda-documentation-11-1
  cuda-driver-dev-11-1 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-455 cuda-gdb-11-1
  cuda-libraries-11-1 cuda-libraries-dev-11-1 cuda-memcheck-11-1
  cuda-nsight-11-1 cuda-nsight-compute-11-1 cuda-nsight-systems-11-1
  cuda-nvcc-11-1 cuda-nvdisasm-11-1 cuda-nvml-dev-11-1 cuda-nvprof-11-1
  cuda-nvprune-11-1 cuda-nvrtc-11-1 cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-1 cuda-nvtx-11-1
  cuda-nvvp-11-1 cuda-runtime-11-1 cuda-samples-11-1 cuda-sanitizer-11-1
  cuda-toolkit-11-1 cuda-tools-11-1 cuda-visual-tools-11-1 dkms libcublas-11-1
  libcublas-dev-11-1 libcufft-11-1 libcufft-dev-11-1 libcurand-11-1
  libcurand-dev-11-1 libcusolver-11-1 libcusolver-dev-11-1 libcusparse-11-1
  libcusparse-dev-11-1 libnpp-11-1 libnpp-dev-11-1 libnvidia-cfg1-455
  libnvidia-common-455 libnvidia-compute-455 libnvidia-decode-455
  libnvidia-encode-455 libnvidia-extra-455 libnvidia-fbc1-455 libnvidia-gl-455
  libnvidia-ifr1-455 libnvjpeg-11-1 libnvjpeg-dev-11-1 libxnvctrl0
  nsight-compute-2020.2.0 nsight-systems-2020.3.4 nvidia-compute-utils-455
  nvidia-dkms-455 nvidia-driver-455 nvidia-kernel-common-455
  nvidia-kernel-source-455 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime nvidia-settings
  nvidia-utils-455 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455
0 upgraded, 74 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 22,1 MB/2 553 MB of archives.
After this operation, 5 581 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

All of which are Cuda 11.1 packages.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

To Install cuda 11.0 run:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-11-0
```

Comment: He asked 11.1 !

Comment: so why he installed the 11.0 repo?