# E: Unable to locate package cuda-11-0

Tags: apt, nvidia, cuda

I read [Cuda 11.0 installs 11.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283968/cuda-11-0-installs-11-1-on-ubuntu-18-04) so tried `sudo apt-get install cuda-11-0` but the result is an "unable to locate" error.

```
$ sudo apt-get install cuda-11-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cuda-11-0
```

I did this exactly same command 2 or 3 years ago, it for sure worked. But now it doesn't. I'm very confused. Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you do all the other steps in the question part?

Comment: I think I haven't. I tried it and it seems working with `cuda`, thanks.